# python: Overloading ** dict unpacking

Tags: python, dictionary, overloading

I would like to be able to unpack an object from a dict-similar class.

current:
`f(**m.to_dict())`

preferred
`f(**m)`

This would work if `starstarprepare` existed:

```py
class M:
    #... __getitem__, __setitem__
    def __starstarprepare__(self):
        md = self.to_dict()
        return md
```

Comment: Try define `.keys()` and `__getitem__`, if I remember correctly I think those are the main two bits that are needed for something to work with other dict things.

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution for me.

Comment: I posted an answer but if you post an identical one I will accept it.

Comment: Np, glad to help, I don't particularly care about the points on here so it's cool haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution due to @peter

```
class M:
    # ... __getitem__  and other functions
    def keys(self):
        k = self.to_dict().keys()
        return k
```

Answer (score 5):

`**` works with any mapping type. One way to make `M` a mapping type is to subclass `collections.abc.Mapping` and implement `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, and `__len__`:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping

class M(Mapping):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = 5

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield 'a'
        yield 'b'

    def __len__(self):
        return 2


def foo(**kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        print(k, v)


m = M()
foo(**m)
```

If you already have a `to_dict` method, all three of the magic methods can be wrappers around the corresponding `dict` methods.

```
class M(Mapping):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = 5

    def to_dict(self):
        return {'a': self.a, 'b': self.b}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.to_dict()[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.to_dict())

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.to_dict())
```

Comment: Thanks, but I with this route I think that `class M(dict)` is simpler?

Comment: Sure, if you want `M` to be a `dict`. But that obscures the fact that `**` doesn't *require* a `dict` (or a subclass of `dict`). `dict` is only special in that it is the only *built-in* mapping type in Python.

Comment: The unpacking syntax effectively takes *any* mapping type (even one that is not a `dict`) and creates a `dict` for use inside the body of the function.

Comment: I agree with your comment that it is the general unpacking I am seeking and that the dict subclass is not a good solution. But, apparently an object only needs __getitem__ and keys to be unpackable.

Comment: I suspect that the unpacking code uses keys if possible, otherwise uses `__len__` and `__iter__` to simulate `keys`. Outside of this ABC, I don't know of any documentation that specially outlines what `**` requires, since clearly the minimal interface for `Mapping` is not the same.

Comment: (In particular, it may be a CPython implementation detail that `keys` is sufficient. The same code might not work, for example, in PyPY.)

Comment: `__len__` and `__iter__` were unnecessary for me (but `keys()` was required)

fwiw I did not subclass `Mapping` so likely `Mapping` has a default implementation of `keys()` that utilizes `__len__` and `__iter__`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.abc.Mapping`.

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping

class M(Mapping):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.to_dict())
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.to_dict()[item]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.to_dict())
```